# How to "diagram as code" zoomable block diagram in Python, or with another tool Python can interact with?

Tags: python, diagram

Is there a package in Python (or JavaSs) that can generate GUI like in the image below? Allowing to:

1. Generate block diagrams as code
2. Zoom into\out-of blocks interactively.

There are packages that support "Diagrams as code" in Python ([Diagrams](https://github.com/mingrammer/diagrams), [BlockDiag](https://pypi.org/project/blockdiag/)), but These show the entire diagram at once and are not interactive.

I describe below the behavior I want to support.

> I want to describe a router that contains components and in turn these
> components can contain additional sub components. In the high level of
> the diagram (top left corner) I can click on "Router A" and reveal its
> contents. I can continue and click on "Protocol 1 Handler" (bottom
> left corner) to zoom in again and get the view of the logic inside
> that block (Right bottom corner).
>
> In addition, clicking on the arrow will display details about all the
> interfaces between the routers (right top corner).

[image]

Comment: One solution I am considering is to display an interactive hierarchy of components and generate each level as the user clicks on the item in the list instead of the block itself.

Comment: When you say "python and GUI", what toolkit are you looking for? Or is this about rendering a web UI?

Comment: The ideal thing would be an interactive HTML output. To either display online in response to some query or files I can store with logs of the system. Another option is that I will generate the "code" that the "tool" will use to generate the GUI and I will store the "code" with the logs.